# How to determine the 64-bit signed integer type and printf specifier with CMake?

Tags: c, cmake

In my project's **`CMakeLists.txt`** I have:

```
include(CheckIncludeFiles)
configure_file(config.h.in config.h @ONLY)
```

and I want to check for my platform's 64-bit integer type and printf conversion specifier for it, for use in C via **`config.h`**. How do I do that?

Note: I know that on most systems we can just use **`stdint.h`**'s **`int64_t`** type, but suppose I can't assume **`stdint.h`** is available.

Comment: The [fixed-width integers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) and the `<stdint.h>` header file is not optional. It's a mandatory part of C since the C99 standard. If your compiler supports C99 then it must have that header. You can always add that as a requirement to your project, that it must be compiled by a C99 (or later) complying compiler. Then you don't have to check for it at all.

Comment: If it is an implementation that conforms to the C standard (99 or 11), `stdint.h` will be available. There might not be an `int64_t` but, if there isn't, it will be because the implementation does not support 64 bit integers.

Comment: @JeremyP: Well, suppose it might not be.

Comment: @einpoklum If `int64_t` is not defined, there is no supported 64 bit signed type so you can just error out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use:

```
include(CheckIncludeFile)
check_include_file(stdint.h HAVE_STDINT_H)
```

or

```
include(CheckIncludeFileCXX)
check_include_file_cxx(cstdint HAVE_CSTDINT)
```

For `int64_t` I would do:

```
include(CheckTypeSize)
check_type_size("int64_t" SIZEOF_INT64_T)
check_type_size("long long" SIZEOF_LONG_LONG)
check_type_size("long" SIZEOF_LONG)

if(SIZEOF_INT64_T EQUAL "8")
  set(INT64_T "int64_t")
elseif(SIZEOF_LONG EQUAL "8")
  set(INT64_T "long")
elseif(SIZEOF_LONG_LONG EQUAL "8")
  set(INT64_T "long long")
else()
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Can't find suitable int64_t")
endif()
message(STATUS "Found int64_t: ${INT64_T}")
```

and then use a compile_definitions() or configure_file() to propagate it in your source code...

Also, you can try to look for the symbols otherwise:

```
set(TEST_INCLUDES "")
if(HAVE_STDINT_H)
    list(APPEND TEST_INCLUDES "stdint.h")
endif()
include(CheckCXXSymbolExists)
check_cxx_symbol_exists(int64_t "${TEST_INCLUDES}" HAVE_INT64_T)
```

src: https://github.com/Mizux/Cbc/blob/master/cmake/CheckEnv.cmake

Comment: `check_cxx_symbol_exists` won't work. As per [CMake docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CheckCXXSymbolExists.html): "If the symbol is a type, enum value, or C++ template it will not be recognized: consider using the CheckTypeSize or CheckSourceCompiles module instead."

Answer (score 2):

Do assume that `stdint.h` is available. All conforming implementations of C compilers must have it, even freestanding ones (embedded). See chapter 4 of the C standard.

Formally, parts of stdint.h are optional, but every sane compiler will implement all of it. If some weird compiler decides not to implement it, it is really their problem, not yours. Nobody will use that compiler.

Format specifiers are standardized through `inttypes.h`, such as `PRIu64`. `inttypes.h` will reasonably be supported by all systems that support `stdio.h` (conforming hosted implementations).

Comment: What do you mean by "conforming hosted implementations"? Also, `stdint.h` was introduced with C99, and if you want to generate a Makefile for a system with a non-C99 compiler you can't assume it's there. Now, you could ask "Why are you assuming a non-C99-compiler system will have CMake" and that's a valid question, but I don't want to go into those details here.

Comment: "Formally, parts of stdint.h are optional, but every sane compiler will implement all of it." - not necessarily. If there is no 64 bit int type, `int64_t` must not be defined (§ 7.20 point 4). So if it is there, use it, if it is not there, assume the compiler does not support it.

Comment: @einpoklum According to the mentioned chapter in the standard, a "conforming hosted implementation" is a C compiler for hosted systems (running on OS) that implements all of the C standard. Why would you generate make files for 20+ years old non-standard compliant compilers, in the year 2018?

Comment: @Lundin "Why would you generate make files for 20+ years old non-standard compliant compilers" - if you were using the Microsoft C compiler perhaps :-)

Comment: @JeremyP I was mostly referring to types like `uintptr_t`, which is stupidly not required, only optional.

Comment: @JeremyP If you use Visual Studio in C mode, you already threw standard C and portability out the door. The question was tagged C, so we'll have to assume it is about the use of compliant C compilers and not about something-else compilers.

Comment: @Lundin I know, that's why I mentioned it and with a smiley at the end.